# Angular 8 redirect to another component after checking conditions loop

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, angular8, angular2-routing

Here I want to check that each product stock is less than quantity.. If any one of the product quantity is higher than stock, then out of stock message have to be show on console. But here the condition is working before foreach.. It is not checking the conditio in loop..
how to solve this with **async/await** methord..

**TS**

```
stockFlag=false
  orderProducts(){
    this.cartDatas.forEach(element => {
      this.cartService.checkAvailability(element.productId.id).subscribe((data:any)=>{
        if(+data.message < Number(+element.quantity))
        {
          this.stockFlag = true
        }
      })
      console.log(!this.stockFlag)
    })
      if(this.stockFlag){
        this.route.navigate(['newpage'])
      }else{
          console.log("out of stock")
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(+data.message < Number(+element.quantity))
```

i think you have a typo there : remove the +

```
if(data.message < Number(+element.quantity))
```

(and the data.message is probably a string maybe?)

Comment: there is no error in type the problem is before foreach the outer condition is being processing..